# how to calculate difference in hours including current day

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Column `date` is `datetime` format.
I need to display how much **hours** is remeining till a certain date.

```
$st = $db->query("select ev, date from event where ev = 'ng'");
$row = $st->fetch();
$d1 = new DateTime($row['date']);
$d2 = new DateTime();
$diff = $d1->diff($d2);
$diff = $diff->days * 24; // result: 2088
```

So this works, but hours of current day are not calculated. I tried:

```
$diff = $diff->hours;
```

and got the notice:

```
Undefined property: DateInterval::$hours
```

Any help?

Comment: `hours` is not a valid property of the `DateInterval` class. Check the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) for the correct property names.

Comment: @bonaca im tired lol

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$diff->days` returns the remaining days you can times that by 24 to get the hours, then you just add the remaining hours for the day on that, so essentially what your doing but just add the remaining hours for total hours

```
$st = $db->query("select ev, date from event where ev = 'ng'");
$row = $st->fetch();
$d1 = new DateTime($row['date']);
$d2 = new DateTime();
$diff = $d1->diff($d2);
// (days * 24) = hours + remaining hours
$hours = ($diff->days * 24) + $diff->h;
```

**Example:** 1 day 5 hours = 29 https://3v4l.org/KDS9r

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the diff object, just format it so you can get the hours

```
$d1 = new DateTime($row['date']);
$d2 = new DateTime();
$diff = $d1->diff($d2);
```

to get the number of hours

```
echo ($diff->d * 24) + $diff->h
```

Comment: thanks, but how to get only hours, no days plus hours?

Comment: @bonaca I've revised my answer